# MS Excel - Locate like terms in cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to locate and identify neighboring lines with a matching word.

For example:

```
| --Col A--     | -Col B- |
| That Car!!    | [blank] |
| Blue Car$     | [blank] |
| Ponies^!_     | [blank] |
| Car Sales     | [blank] |
| Detroit__     | [blank] |
| Banana^       | [blank] |
```

"That Car!!" and "Blue Car$" are neighboring cells both containing the word "car."

I cannot figure out how to write a =formula() in Col B to identify matching words.  All the formula needs to do is identify the duplicate word (not case sensitive) and output the word "BLANK" for the second line.

Remove Duplicates will do the rest.

The line containing "Car Sales" will not be identified.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have some questions according to your sample. Thank~ 1. Does the matching word you set it in advance, and then enter it into the formula? Do you want to find the **neighboring cells** in one colmun contains the specific word? If yes, why B2 and B3 both are "Blank"?

Comment: The [blank] in the table above is a placeholder only.  Pretend those are literally blank cells.  Sorry.  The table would not allow me to have it empty.

Comment: In your example, would `Blue Car$` be the only item marked for removal?

Comment: Yes, it is the only one meant to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This stackoverflow answer contains a custom VBA function to calculate similarity between texts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42657518/4721734

Using that, you can write something like this formula:

`=IF(Similarity(A2,A3)>=0.5,A3,"BLANK")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Power Query solution (that will also remove that unwanted row)

Power query is available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table8"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    
//remove the non-alphabet characters and split into List of Words   
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Remove non-alpha characters", 
        each Text.Split(Text.Combine(
            List.Accumulate(Text.ToList([Column1]),{},
                (state,current)=> if List.Contains({"A".."Z"," ","a".."z"},current) then  
                List.Combine({state,{current}}) else state))," ")),

//Add a column representing the previous row
    ShiftedList = {null} &  List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(#"Added Custom", "Remove non-alpha characters"),1),
    Custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Added Custom") & {ShiftedList},
    prevRow = Table.FromColumns(Custom1, Table.ColumnNames(#"Added Custom") & {"Previous Row"}),
    
//Mark "BLANK" if previous row has the same word in the list of words
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(prevRow, "Blank", each 
        try if List.ContainsAny([#"Remove non-alpha characters"],[Previous Row],Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
             then "BLANK" else null otherwise null),
    
//filter out the non-null rows
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([Blank] = null)),

//Remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Remove non-alpha characters", "Previous Row", "Blank"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]